# Delete conversion changes semantics

Tags: go, semantics, goland

GoLand IDE by JetBrains offers automatic deletion of redundant type conversion. But there is a message:

> Delete conversion (changes semantics)

I cannot figure out what is meant by ***changes semantics***. What does it actually change?

[image: Screenshot]

Extra info:

[image: More info]

Comment: If you find the corresponding rule (right click, then explore the options to find one that leads to the inspection settings) - it will come with small description what they mean.

Comment: @zerkms Right, I updated the post with inspection info

Comment: What type is `got`? It looks like it's `float32` already?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, `got` is `float32` already

Comment: @zerkms I don't understand why semantics would be changed by removing redundant conversion. Why would anything change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoLand indeed shows *Possibly redundant type conversion* when an expression is of a floating type. In all other cases, the message is *Redundant type conversion*. The uncertainty in the former statement is connected to the fact that conversion from float to float is sometimes used to prevent the compiler's Fused Multiply Add (FMA) instruction selection to avoid rounding errors. Please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/mdempsky/unconvert/issues/40) for more details. I would agree, though, that *changes semantic* is perhaps too strict as a conversion result depends on many factors. So, I've changed the wording to *may change semantics*. I've also updated the inspection's description, so it contains this information. These changes will appear in GoLand 2020.3.